# I am creating a notepad in java i have been able to copy the selected text but is enable to paste it at location of cursor

Tags: java

```
private void TextAreaMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) { 
    if (TextArea.getSelectedText() != null){
        String s = TextArea.getSelectedText();
}
```

This is the code i am using for copying

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i want to paste this selected text at the location of cursor when user presses the paste button

Comment: Assuming your question is about pasting, where's your code for pasting? It doesn't make any sense to post code for something that's working when your problem is with code that *isn't* working.

Comment: i understand that but im unable to think of anything that can help me to paste selected text at position of cursor.So i thought it would be useful if i put the code which i was using for copying

Comment: Perhaps try [`TextArea.getDocument().insertString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html#insertString-int-java.lang.String-javax.swing.text.AttributeSet-) to add text into the JTextArea.

Comment: @Surbhit Why don't you start with some tutorial information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/cutpaste.html). You've submitted a poorly formed question on a fundamental issue that you could have researched yourself, hence the massive amount of down voting. Please familiarize yourself wit Stack Overflow's standards [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert text at the cursor's position use:

```
String copiedText = "";

if ("user presses copy button") {
    if (textArea.getSelectedText() != null) {
        copiedText = textArea.getSelectedText();
    }
}

if ("user presses paste button") {
    textArea.insert(copiedText, textArea.getCaretPosition());
}
```